# how to find escape character \ in a string?

Tags: design-patterns, escaping, character, expression

Please consider following code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

        int count = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("X");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("5\\yeyyyyyyy");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(matcher.start()+"..."+matcher.group());
        }
        System.out.println("The total number of occurrences "+count);

    }
```

1) If I write x=5 in above program then I get following output:

```
0...5
The total number of occurrences 1
```

So I got information that 5 is at 0 index and it is only one time in the given string.

2) Similary We know that // is at 1 index and it is only one time in the given string. How can I get this as output?

I am trying to write

```
x=//
```

I am getting compile time error.

I hope I made you guys understood of my point.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the double quotation. So in your case that would be "\\\\".

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\");
```

In case you want the forwarding slash, then: "\\/"